# Replacing NAs in R dataframe with zeros conditional on an id

Tags: r, dataframe, na

I have a data.frame that has several NAs. I already know that if a column has some zero values for some firm, then those NAs are zeros as well. What would be a good way to replace those and only those NAs with zeros.

An example:

I want to transform this

```
  FIRMID    VAR1     VAR2        
  FIRM1     0        1
  FIRM1     NA       NA
  FIRM2     1        0
  FIRM2     NA       NA
```

to this

```
  FIRMID    VAR1     VAR2        
  FIRM1     0        1
  FIRM1     0        NA
  FIRM2     1        0
  FIRM2     NA       0
```

EDIT: number of variables is possibly large and therefore I want to find a way to apply this neatly to all of them at the same time without manually entering each variable name.

Comment: Are the values for `VAR1`, `VAR2` always: 0,1,NA?

Comment: They are NAs, zeros and non-zeros. So 1 was only an example representing a non-zero.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is another `ddply` alternative where you don't have to specify the variable names which the function should be applied on. By using `numcolwise`, the function operates on all numerical columns.

```
library(plyr)

myfun <- function(x){
  x[is.na(x) & (sum(!is.na(x) & x == 0) > 0)] <- 0
  x}

ddply(df, .(FIRMID), numcolwise(myfun))

#   FIRMID VAR1 VAR2
# 1  FIRM1    0    1
# 2  FIRM1    0   NA
# 3  FIRM2    1    0
# 4  FIRM2   NA    0
```

Or in `base` R, where I assume that the first column contains the grouping variable (`dat[ , -1]`). You could of course refer to it by name instead.

```
df2 <- do.call(rbind, by(df, df[ , "FIRMID"], function(dat){
  sapply(dat[ , -1], function(x){
    myfun(x)
  })
}))

data.frame(FIRMID = df$FIRMID, df2)

#   FIRMID VAR1 VAR2
# 1  FIRM1    0    1
# 2  FIRM1    0   NA
# 3  FIRM2    1    0
# 4  FIRM2   NA    0
```

**Update** 'myfun' can be written much simpler. Thanks @Arun for the suggestion!

```
myfun <- function(x){
  x[is.na(x) & any(x == 0)] <- 0
  x}
```

Answer (score 3):

If you don't have only integers you might need to adjust this for comparing floating point numbers:

```
DF <- read.table(text="FIRMID    VAR1     VAR2        
FIRM1     0        1
FIRM1     NA       NA
FIRM2     1        0
FIRM2     NA       NA", header=TRUE)

na_replace <- function(x) {
  if (any(na.omit(x)==0L)) x[is.na(x)] <- 0L
  x
}

library(plyr)
ddply(DF, .(FIRMID), transform, 
      VAR1=na_replace(VAR1),
      VAR2=na_replace(VAR2))

#  FIRMID VAR1 VAR2
#1  FIRM1    0    1
#2  FIRM1    0   NA
#3  FIRM2    1    0
#4  FIRM2   NA    0
```

Answer (score 2):

you can use ddply here. but it would be very inefficient if the data.frame is very large. if not, then you could try:

```
your.data.frame<-ddply(your.data.frame,~FIRMID,function(x){
if ( any(x[!is.na(x$VAR1),"VAR1"]==0)){x[is.na(x$VAR1),"VAR1"]<-0}
if ( any(x[!is.na(x$VAR2),"VAR2"]==0)){x[is.na(x$VAR2),"VAR2"]<-0}
x})
```

but very inelegant

EDIT: my code before didn't worked, so I fixed it :)